# How do I use mongoose model in a class?

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongoose, jestjs, es6-class

I'm trying to use a Mongoose model inside my ES6 class with typescript, everything works fine in Postman but when I try to test it in jest it doesn't work.

product.service.ts

```
export class ProductService{
  constructor(private readonly model: Model<ProductType>){} //I think I'm inserting the model wrong?

  public getAllProducts = async (): Promise<ProductType[]> => {
    return await this.model.find({}); //works fine in Postman but says undefined in Jest
  };
}

export const productService = new ProductService(ProductModel)
```

So when I try to test this is Jest, it returns to me `TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined`

Can anyone advise how to properly use Mongoose models in classes?